# Meteor server .remove code doesn't work when deployed

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have some code that cleans out elements in a loop when they are no longer needed running on the server:

```
setInterval(serverLoop, 1000);

function serverLoop() {
  Fiber(function() {
    Blocks.remove({type: "hit"});
    Letters.remove({timeout: {$lte: 0}});
  }).run();
}
```

The code works on localhost:3000, but when I deploy to meteor.com, the .remove does not work.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: What version of meteor is your project using (use `meteor --version`) in the project directory

Comment: @Akshat I'm using 0.6.3.1

Comment: Does using the snippet below work instead?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `Meteor.setInterval`, http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_setinterval instead?

```
Meteor.setInterval(serverLoop, 1000);

function serverLoop() {
    Blocks.remove({type: "hit"});
    Letters.remove({timeout: {$lte: 0}});
}
```

Comment: Sorry, just got to try this out today.  I tried it but it is still not being removed from the server.  I currently have insecure and autopublish on.  Is there anything different in production that will cause it to not remove stuff in deployment only?